# Ruby: Why does nil.to_s return "", but nil.inspect returns "nil"

Tags: ruby, null

Why does `nil.to_s` return `""`, but `nil.inspect` returns `"nil"` (when apparently `.inspect` uses the `.to_s` method)

Answer (score 25):

The ["inspect" method of the Object class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is supposed to return a *human-readable* version of the object.

The human-readable version of `nil` is "nil" and not "" (which is the human readable version of the string `""`).
That's why `nil.inspect` should return "nil", whereas `nil.to_s` returns "" in order for `"a string" + nil` to return `"a string"` as it is generally expected (in other languages for instance).

Answer (score 6):

See the documentation on [`NilClass.inspect`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/NilClass#inspect-instance_method). It states it will return `"nil"` and does not guarantee equivalency with `to_s`.

Comment: Sorry for the out-dated link, I answered this using my phone.